# DB Error: syntax error INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache a &lt; problem

Tags: error, smartgroups, contact-view

I'm using Wordpress 5.8 and civicrm 5.39.0.

I think i found a bug. I get an error when i want to view the smart groups on a contact card. The error is:
INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_e272cc7d39a4f55ebaea6f3ecbb56684 (group_id, contact_id) SELECT 113 AS group_id, contact_a.id as id FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE ( ( contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed' AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 113 ) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '; '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT ...' at line 1]

I copied the "SELECT" statemant and run it from the command line, but i dident get any error's. After searching and print the $sql varaiable from the code in "CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php" (around line 820), i saw that the '<' is really a '&lt;'. And i fixed it temporary with "$sql = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $sql);".

Can someone reproduce this error?
And i can't see where it gose wrong, can someone find out where the real problem comes from? (and possible a fix)

The full error is:

Fout Veld   Foutwaarde
Type    DB_Error
Code    -2
Message DB Error: syntax error
Mode    16
UserInfo    INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_c626e96b4b2c3d1ef1860608883c1550 (group_id, contact_id) SELECT 113 AS group_id, contact_a.id as id FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE ( ( contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed' AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 113 ) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '; '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT ...' at line 1]
DebugInfo   INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_c626e96b4b2c3d1ef1860608883c1550 (group_id, contact_id) SELECT 113 AS group_id, contact_a.id as id FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE ( ( contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed' AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 113 ) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '; '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT ...' at line 1]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: syntax error in /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: syntax error in unknown on line unknown
  Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:922
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: syntax…', -2, 16, Array, 'INSERT IGNORE IN…')    /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:997
2   DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, Array, 'INSERT IGNORE IN…')   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -2, 16, Array, 'INSERT IGNORE IN…', 'DB_Error', true)    /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1928
5   DB_common->raiseError(-2, null, null, 'INSERT IGNORE IN…', '1064 ** You have…') /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:936
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:406
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('INSERT IGNORE IN…') /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1234
8   DB_common->query('INSERT IGNORE IN…')   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query('INSERT IGNORE IN…')  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1829
10  DB_DataObject->query('INSERT IGNORE IN…')   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:454
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('INSERT IGNORE IN…', true)  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1599
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('INSERT IGNORE IN…') /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:836
13  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::insertGroupContactsIntoTempTable('civicrm_tmp_e_gc…', 113, 42, null) /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:640
14  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::buildGroupContactTempTable(Array, Object(CRM_Utils_SQL_TempTable))   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:380
15  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:3167
16  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache(Array, 'civicrm_group_co…', 'contact_a', 'IN')  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:3068
17  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group(Array) /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:1830
18  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle(Array, false)  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:2068
19  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(false)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:575
20  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(null) /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:524
21  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct(Array, Array, Array, true, false, 1, true, true, false, null, 'AND', null, 1)    /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:4594
22  CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery(Array, Array, null, null, 0, 0, false)  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:152
23  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::add(Array)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:135
24  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::loadAll()    /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php:446
25  CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::contactGroup(4271)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/ContactSmartGroup.php:41
26  CRM_Contact_Page_View_ContactSmartGroup->browse()   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/ContactSmartGroup.php:89
27  CRM_Contact_Page_View_ContactSmartGroup->run(Array, null)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:313
28  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
29  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
30  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1172
31  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
32  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:327
33  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-includes/plugin.php:470
34  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /domains/eestertest.nl/crm/wp-admin/admin.php:259
35  {main}

Kind regards,

Comment: It seems ok on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org. You could try around line 820 putting `CRM_Core_Error::backtrace('testing', TRUE);` and then check in ConfigAndLog to see if the trace tells you where it's coming from.

Comment: If you run this query against the database manually (using phpmyadmin or whatever) what happens: `SELECT 113 AS group_id, contact_a.id as id FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE ( ( contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000' ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed' AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 113 )`

Comment: If I run the query it goes well. but what i see is that the "contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000' )" is in fact "contact_a.modified_date &lt; '20190501000000' )", that's the whole problem! It runs perfectly when i add "$sql = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $sql);" to the code, but without it I get the error!? Strange, not? I cannot see where the problem comes from?

Comment: Are you able to edit the smart group criteria? Maybe just re-save it? The `contact_a.modified_date < '20190501000000'` part would be coming from the smart group criteria, so maybe something is messed up in the smart group.

Comment: I will try it !